# Is high AIC a bad feature of the model?

Tags: r, aic, model-comparison

I have a model with AIC equal to 78809. Does this mean this is a very bad model or the intepretation should be different? There are 15 variables, 2-level response variable and 40000 rows.

`step()` function from `R` statistical package returns almost the same AIC: 78600. Is there even a sense of applying `step()` function in that case?

Comment: You compare AIC metrics of different models. The absolute value has little meaning.

Comment: It is questionable if `step` does any good: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection

Answer (score 6):

This is from the description of [AIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion):

> The Akaike information criterion (AIC) is a measure of the relative
>   quality of a statistical model for a given set of data. As such, AIC
>   provides a means for model selection.

I don't pay attention to the absolute value of AIC. I only use it to compare in-sample fit of the candidate models. Note, that if you're building the forecasting models, it is important to also consider out-of-sample fit.

Comment: +1. You can't interpret the absolute value of AIC. (Different software packages may well give completely different AICs on the same data for the same model.) What you *can* interpret is the difference in AIC between different models applied to the same data. Burnham & Anderson give some rough rules of thumb: a difference of 2 means that both models are essentially equally good, 5 means that the model with the lower AIC is a bit better, 10 is pretty strong evidence that the lower AIC model is better.

Answer (score 2):

As others said, there is not much point in evaluating a single model according to the absolute value of its AIC.

The point is to compare the AIC values of different models and **the model which has lower AIC value than the other is better than the other in the sense that it is less complex but still a good fit for the data.**

In no way I mean that *ONLY less complex model = lower AIC*. I am saying "less complex but still a good fit for the data". Obviously, a more complex problem may be preferable if your model is underfitting so obviously it is not necessary that a less complex model is better or has a lower AIC but in general a less complex problem which is not underfitting is better than a more complex one.

Comment: (-1) You probably do not mean this, but your answer implies that less complex models = lower AIC and better. But it is not necessary that a less complex model is better or has a lower AIC. Sometimes you need a more complex model!

Comment: In no serious way you can infer from my post that ONLY less complex model = lower AIC. At my post I am saying "less complex but still a good fit for the data". Obviously, a more complex problem may be preferable if your model is underfitting so obviosly as you are saying "it is not necessary that a less complex model is better or has a lower AIC" but in general a less complex problem which is not underfitting is better than a more complex one.

Comment: I think it's a reasonable interpretation of your words, though I understand that it's not exactly what you mean. I hope you will edit your answer to make your meaning clearer than it presently is, in both answer and comment (I'll gladly remove my downvote when that happens).

Comment: @mkt is not alone -- I would have read your original answer exactly as mkt did. Had I seen the answer as it stood at that point, I would also likely have downvoted for the same reason.